# Color picker box missing from Chrome inspector source page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Running Chrome Version 103.0.5060.114 and noticed today that the color picker box is missing entirely from the Chrome inspector source page. The color picker box is still visible on the elements page, however when I click on it it doesn't automatically select the eyedropper like it has in the past. Anyone else experiencing this issue or able to fix this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiFnW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is driving me mad how they keep messing stuff up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The color picker bug in Sources panel is fixed in Chrome 104. It will land soon in end of July.

Another issue regarding eyedropper behaviour change is filed here: [crbug.com/1345827](https://crbug.com/1345827). You can put in your comments in the bug on how it affects you and subscribe to the bug for progress.

[image]